# Virtually abelian centralizers

Tags: gr.group-theory, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory

This is a sort of a follow-up question to [Limits of conjugated subgroups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194258/limits-of-conjugated-subgroups) (though it might not seem at first glance to have much to do with it.)

Anyway, I'm wondering what sort of groups have the property that the centralizer of an element of infinite order is virtually abelian. For example hyperbolic groups are known to have this property: the infinite cyclic subgroup $\langle g\rangle$ has finite index in $C(g)$.

That's about the extent of my knowledge in this question.

In particular I'm interested in groups acting by isometries on a CAT(0) space (especially fundamental groups of NPC-spaces), semihyperbolic groups etc.

Of course, any information someone might be able to provide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: All subgroups of $SL_2(\mathbf{C})$ have this property.

Comment: Or ${\mathbb Z} \wr {\mathbb Z}$ (the restricted wreath product).

Comment: Commutative transitive groups (i.e. those where all centralizers of all non-identity elements are abelian) would in particular have this property: this may not give new examples that have not already been mentioned, but may prove useful for looking things up in the literature

Comment: @DerekHolt $\mathbf{Z}\wr\mathbf{Z}$ is a subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbf{C})$...

Comment: @YemonChoi Some Olshanski monsters are commutative transitive and certainly not subgroups of $SL_2$. Also using that commutative transitive is stable under free product provides further examples.

Comment: Thompson's group $F$ acts properly on a (complete) CAT(0) cube complex, but the centralizer of an element of $F$ is the product of a free abelian group with some isomorphic copies of $F$ (according to Guba and Sapir).

Comment: @Seirios Yes, I also just realized that if the centre $Z(G)$ contains an element of infinite order (which might very well happen) then the centralizer of that element is, of course the whole group.

Comment: Further to Seirios' comment above, although it's true that groups acting properly on CAT(0) complexes may not have the virtually abelian stabilizers (think about a direct product of two free groups for an easy example), there *is* a splitting theorem for centralizers in this context. See Bridson and Haefliger for details.

Comment: Another remark that might be of interest: limits of commutative transitive groups (eg torsion-free hyperbolic groups) are themselves commutative transitive.  This provdes many examples, eg limit groups.